# Where can I get a basic list of all permissions that I can deny/allow in PEX?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I am currently building my server, and I chose the PEX Bukkit plugin.

It is so far very easy to use. (Although I am a programmer, so any weird settings file that you have to edit using the command line hooked via SSH to your Raspberry Pi is easy.) That's not the point.

I have been wondering is there a Wiki or similar page that lists all the basic permissions in a fresh Bukkit install? I can easily get them for my mods mods; almost all of them are well supported and have a little section on their page. The ones that aren't I would never give away the power to use them "cough cough anti-greif." However I cannot find a simple list of the basic permissions that will be compatible with PEX.

**What I want are things like "stop server" or "help" that are standard to Minecraft.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the permission nodes that are integrated into Bukkit already, such as `/say`, `/plugin`, `/help`, `/stop`, etc. You can find them all on the [Bukkit Wiki](http://wiki.bukkit.org/CraftBukkit_commands), in a nice, organized table.

Comment: The Modifyworld permissions are no longer relevant in the current version of PEX because Modifyworld is a separate plugin from PEX. They are no longer bundled together. You would have to go download Modifyworld and then add it to the server to use those permission nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
---------- Permission nodes for Bukkit ----------
bukkit.command.version - Gives the version number of the server.
bukkit.command.plugins - Lists all installed plugins on the server.
bukkit.command.reload - Stops and restarts all plugins on the server.
bukkit.command.timings - Records timings for all plugin events.
bukkit.command.tell - Allows the user to privately message another player.
bukkit.command.kill - Allows the player to kill themselves, returning to spawn.
bukkit.command.me - Says a message from the player's point of view (emote)
bukkit.command.help - Shows a list of server commands
bukkit.command.kick - Removes a player from the server.
bukkit.command.ban.player - Bans a player from the server.
bukkit.command.ban.list - Shows the banned players.
bukkit.command.unban.player - Pardons a banned player.
bukkit.command.ban.ip - Bans an IP address from the server.
bukkit.command.unban.ip - Pardons a banned IP address.
bukkit.command.op.give - Turns a player into a server operator.
bukkit.command.op.take - Removes server operator status from a player.
bukkit.command.teleport - Moves player to another player or coordinates.
bukkit.command.give - Gives player blocks/items 
bukkit.command.stop - Gracefully stops the server
bukkit.command.save.perform - Forces a server-wide level save of the terrain.
bukkit.command.save.disable - Disables automatic terrain saving 
bukkit.command.save.enable - Re-enables automatic terrain saving.
bukkit.command.list - Lists all currently connected players.
bukkit.command.say - Broadcasts a message to all players as the server.
bukkit.command.whitelist.enable - Enable whitelist (only listed players my join)
bukkit.command.whitelist.disable - Disable whitelist (all players may join)
bukkit.command.whitelist.add - Add a player to the whitelist
bukkit.command.whitelist.remove - Remove a player from the whitelist
bukkit.command.whitelist.list - Lists all currently whitelisted players.
bukkit.command.whitelist.reload - Reload the whitelist from file. 
bukkit.command.time.add - Add to the world time.
bukkit.command.time.set - Set the world time.
bukkit.command.gamemode - Change the gamemode of a player.
bukkit.command.xp - Give player xp.
bukkit.command.toggledownfall - Turon on/off current weather.
bukkit.command.defaultgamemode - Change the gamemode of new players joining the   server.
bukkit.command.seed - Outputs the world seed.
bukkit.command.enchant - Enchants the item in the user's hand.
bukkit.command.weather - Changes the weather in-game.
bukkit.command.clear - Clears a user's inventory.
bukkit.command.difficulty - Changes the difficulty of the Server.
bukkit.command.spawnpoint - Sets the spawnpoint of a specified user.
bukkit.command.gamerule - Displays current game rules.
bukkit.command.effect - Adds an effect to player.
bukkit.command.setidletimeout - Sets the servers idle timeout.
bukkit.command.setworldspawn - Sets a worlds's spawn point.
bukkit.command.achievement - Give user an achievement.
bukkit.broadcast.user - Allows the user to receive user broadcasts
bukkit.command.plugins - Allows user to look at plugins. Disables: /pl and /plugins
bukkit.command.ban - Combines the Player ban and the IP ban permissions
bukkit.command.unban - Combines the Player Unban and IP Unban permissions.
bukkit.command.op - Combines the Op Give and Op Take permissions.
bukkit.command.time - Combines the Time Add and Time Set permissions.
bukkit.command.save - Combines the Save Enable, Save Disable and Save Perform permissions.
bukkit.broadcast - Allows the user to receive all broadcast messages.
bukkit.broadcast.admin - Allows the user to receive administrative broadcasts.
```

Source: http://wiki.bukkit.org/CraftBukkit_Commands

Answer (score -2):

http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Command_Reference/Perm is a very good website for all of the essentials permission nodes. :)

Comment: Please summarize the requested information here.  That way, if the site or page ever goes down, your answer is still valid.  Besides, it saves people a click.